# Other Script doesn't work on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, popup

I have a script when the button is clicked. An image will pop up..

And I want to have multiple buttons and multiple images but same div to have same animation on script.

But the problem is, the script only work on just 1 button.

And it doens't show the image.

HTML CODE

```
<button id="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
<div id="PopUpText">Popup contents here</div>
<button id="CloseBtn">Close</button>
</div> </div>

<div id="img2">
<button id="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup" img src="newfinal/images/portfolio6.jpg"> 
<div id="PopUpText">Popup contents here</div>
<button id="CloseBtn">Close</button>
</div> </div>


<div>
some other content that will be behind the popup
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("LearnMoreBtn").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    popup.style.display = "block";
    };

    document.getElementById("CloseBtn").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    popup.style.display = "none";      
    }
    };
```

Here's the demo..

http://jsfiddle.net/j4c7U/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same `id` for both buttons. The `id` should be unique for each element.

Change `LearnMoreBtn` of the second button to `LearnMoreBtn1` and check.

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4c7U/126/)

Comment: The `LearnMoreBtn` is the `id` used for the Script. If I changed the id, it won't popup..

Comment: Check the fiddle I have posted.

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) But I have another problem.. I want to have different images to be popup on each button.. The problem is, it shows the same image when pop up.. Here's the fiddle.. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/j4c7U/127/)

Comment: There is no image posted there.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use same id for all the buttons. getElementById will always return the first element with  given id.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by using query:

http://jsfiddle.net/j4c7U/129/

```
<button class="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<button class="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More2</button>

$('.LearnMoreBtn').click(function(){    
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup.style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: the fiddle you've posted has different html than the one in the question and your answer as well